# gsi client login changes document height and width

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-signin

When I login to my app https://chattyapp.lol using gsi/client on mobile
I notice a scroll is added and the width and height of my app grows 10x more
and I can't find a reason why this is happening or how to solve it

this only occurs on mobile andorid( affects both height and width) and ios( affects width )

I tried setting a max-width, width
nothing worked
I was expecting to enter the app with the properly sizes of the app that should not exceed device viewport

```
<template>
  <button
    v-if="icon === 'google'"
    type="button"
    id="google"
    style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%"
    class="hidden-button"
  >
    <i :class="`fa-brands fa-${icon}`"></i>
  </button>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  name: "login-form",
  created() {
    if (!google) setTimeout(() => {
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID,
        callback: this.handleCallbackResponse
      })
    }, 600)
    google?.accounts?.id?.initialize({
      client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID,
      callback: this.handleCallbackResponse
    })
    if (this.user) this.$router?.push('/personal-info') ??  this.customEventEmit('onGoTo', '/chats')
  },
 methods:{
async handleCallbackResponse(response: any) {
      const googleUser: any = jwt_decode(response.credential)
      const user: { email: string; fullname: string; photo?: string; password: string; googleId: string } = { email: googleUser.email, fullname: googleUser.name, photo: googleUser.picture, password: '', googleId: googleUser.sub }
      try {
        await this.googleLogin(user)
        this.$router?.push('/personal-info') ?? this.customEventEmit('onGoTo', '/chats')
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        this.userMsg = err as string;
      }
    }
},
mounted() {
    if (!google) setTimeout(() => { google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.querySelector('.hidden-button'), { theme: 'outline', size: 'small' }) }, 500)
    google?.accounts?.id?.renderButton(document.querySelector('.hidden-button'), { theme: 'outline', size: 'small' })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason why but right after I login another element with no content is added to the document positioned really far to the left ,It was the reason why when I login a scrollbar on the x-axis was added